# iOS iCarousel customization

Tags: ios, coverflow

I need to do cover flow in my app. For do that I use iCarousel. My problem is that it doesnt show content in way I want it. When I dont set 'type' property of iCarousel object it looks almost fine. Below I enclose screens of how it looks like:

Elements at start:
[image]

Elements at middle:
[image]

Elements at end:
[image]

But I also need to have some move to from of actually selected item like in iCarouselTypeRotary type.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: what is issue ? you want to show ur slides in loop ?

Comment: I want the current selected itam was above all others line in iCarouselTypeRotary. Now all items is on the same level.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question from above comment :
I want the current selected itam was above all others line in iCarouselTypeRotary. Now all items is on the same level.

-> You can use spacing option of iCarousel.

func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, valueFor option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        if (option == .spacing) {
            return value * 2.0
        return value
    }

And then you can have them on different level.